# Add lettering to each line in cell, in complete row

Tags: excel

I am trying to add lettering to each line in each cell, within a row of cells. The number of options differs sometimes. Is there a simple way to do this.
e.g
a) Doxazosin
b) Finasteride
c) Tadalafil
d) Tamsulosin
e) Silodosin

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you asking for a way to code this? You would need to loop through each cell, then loop through each line adding the text you want at the beginning of each

Answer (score 0):

1. Excel isn't suitable for this sort of text processing !
2. It would be best to break down each field to be a separate Excel cell.
3. But yes, it is possible - I have uploaded a solution at https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai5s9-qgdV9waSaw6Te2OaUoAus?e=Miauk5

[image]

Columns C to I find the LineFeed character 10, with overflow handling: I2 is `=IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),$A2,H2+1),LEN($A2))`
Then K to Q add the serial letter at the front of the relevant substring, but are blank if there is no relevant line, K2 is `=IF((C2-B2)>0,K$1&MID($A2,B2+1,C2-B2),"")` 
The column S just concatenates them, so S2 is `=K2&L2&M2&N2&O2&P2&Q2`